# regex to disallow ._ or .- (email validation / javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's my current regex:

```
^([-a-zA-Z0-9'_+\/]+([-.'_+\/][-a-zA-Z0-9'_+\/]+)*)@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+((\.|[-]{1,2})[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$
```

to validate an email address (and yes I know I shouldn't try and validate email addresses except on the simplest of terms, however our email vendor will reject special characters, etc. ).

This regex satisfies all of the requirements except one -

> "No hypen or underscore directly after a period"

Regex is not my specialty, although I was able to get here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex (besides of grouping `(...)` starts with `^[-a-zA-Z0-9'_+\/]+`, which means the beginning `^` is followed with one or more `+` allowed characters `[...]`. In this case they are hyphen, lowercase/uppercase letters, numbers, apostrophe, underscore, plus or foreslash.

Second part is what you need to change. In you regex it is `([-.'_+\/][-a-zA-Z0-9'_+\/]+)*`, which is a pattern that may occur multiple times, but also does not have to `*`. The pattern has two parts: one of allowed characters: hyphen, period/dot, apostrophe, underscore, plus or foreslash; followed by one or more of hyphen, lowercase/uppercase letters, numbers, apostrophe, underscore, plus or foreslash.

If you remove period/dot from that first part of pattern, then this character will not be allowed. But because you want period/dot to be allowed, but not with same character sets, alternative pattern has to be defined.

If this second part will be changed from your `([-.'_+\/][-a-zA-Z0-9'_+\/]+)*` to pattern that has an alternative for period/dot: `([-'_+\/][-a-zA-Z0-9'_+\/]+|\.[a-zA-Z0-9'+\/]+)*`, then the final regex will do what you need. As you can see, `|\.[a-zA-Z0-9'+\/]+` has been added, which reads: or `|` pattern single period/dot followed by one or more of lowercase/uppercase letters, numbers, apostrophe, plus or foreslash.

The final regex then is:

```
^([-a-zA-Z0-9'_+\/]+([-'_+\/][-a-zA-Z0-9'_+\/]+|\.[a-zA-Z0-9'+\/]+)*)@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+((\.|[-]{1,2})[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$
```

Comment: Works - much appreciated! Mind explaining your answer, and then I'll give you credit. Thanks

Comment: @Jason - Regex is not easy to learn, so don't expect to understand it from one example. I have updated my answer with a little juice of explanation, but to learn more about regex you should visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/ or some other online tutorials. Good luck!